# Do I need to have a registered living place to keep my aufenthaltstitel?

Tags: germany, visa

So, here is my situation. I have a course in Germany that lasts three months. I am planning on renting a place there for three month, registering, using that for an autenthalts, then deregistering, going back to my home country, apply to a university in Germany and then returning with my aufenthaltstitel.

My question is, would my aufenthaltstitel become invalid after I deregister from my first place of abode?

Comment: Have you looked for similar questions at [Expatriates.SE]?

Comment: Is your home country in the EU or outside the EU? *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* is tied to a specific purpose and time period. You can always ask this question at service@bamf.bund.de